# Daily, weekly, monthly and yearly reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, group-by, report

Am generating a report using SSRS 2008 R2. In my report I have to generate the report daily, weekly, monthly and yearly basis.

I have Date column in my table, i tried to GroupBy this Date, and its working fine, but I need to display daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. How can I group by these . can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create as many levels of groups as you would like. (There may be some high limit, but four layers of grouping will not be a problem.) Keep right clicking on your tablix and selecting "Add Group..."

Specify your grouping with a VB formula, such as:

```
=Month(Fields!ColumnA.Value)
```

Then display this in the group header as:

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!ColumnA.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date part function in reporting services or in your sql logic to give you the data you need for your grouping

=DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today())